# Bash - Compare rows then print just original rows

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I've got files which look like this, (there can be more columns or rows):

```
dif-1-2-3-4.com 1 1 1
dif-1-2-3-5.com 1 1 2
dif-1-2-4-5.com 1 2 1
dif-1-3-4-5.com 2 1 1
dif-2-3-4-5.com 1 1 1
```

And I want to compare these numbers:

```
1 1 1
1 1 2
1 2 1
2 1 1
1 1 1
```

And print only those rows which do not repeat, so I get this:

```
dif-1-2-3-4.com 1 1 1
dif-1-2-3-5.com 1 1 2
dif-1-2-4-5.com 1 2 1
dif-1-3-4-5.com 2 1 1
```

Comment: you wrote *there can be more columns or rows*. Could be there, let's say, 15 fields with numbers to compare?

Comment: Is sorting allowed like `sort -k2 files | uniq -f1`?

Comment: Yes, @RomanPerekhrest, there can be more fields to compare and not just numbers 1 or 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another simple approach is `sort` with `uniq` using a KEYDEF for fields 2-4 with `sort` and skipping field 1 with `uniq`, e.g.

```
$ sort file.txt -k 2,4 | uniq -f1
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ sort file.txt -k 2,4 | uniq -f1
dif-1-2-3-4.com 1 1 1
dif-1-2-3-5.com 1 1 2
dif-1-2-4-5.com 1 2 1
dif-1-3-4-5.com 2 1 1
```

Comment: if the `sort` version supports `-u`, can also use `sort -u -k 2,4 file.txt`

Comment: Yes, thanks -- that saves an additional subshell too.

Comment: This will *potentially* loose any meaning of the order of the file if that is important. Otherwise, great solution.

Answer (score 2):

Keep a running record of the triples already seen and only print the first time they appear:

```
$ awk '!(($2,$3,$4) in seen) {print; seen[$2,$3,$4]}' file
dif-1-2-3-4.com 1 1 1
dif-1-2-3-5.com 1 1 2
dif-1-2-4-5.com 1 2 1
dif-1-3-4-5.com 2 1 1
```

Comment: Great answer! Are the parentheses surrounding the test after `!` necessary?

Comment: Yes, @archimiro, they are necessary. The outer parens are necessary because `!` has higher precedence than the `in` operator. The inner parens are part of the construction for simulating multidimensional arrays with commas. The same could be written as `!($2 SUBSEP $3 SUBSEP $4 in seen)` in which case only the outer parens are necessary.  See https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Multidimensional.html#Multidimensional and https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Precedence.html for more info.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and the references :). I asked because I removed the outer parens and got the same result. Is this just a case where it works either way? (I'm using GNU Awk 4.1.4).

Comment: With plain awk I get a syntax error.  With GNU awk I get the same as you.  I don't have an explanation for that!

Comment: can be simplified to idiomatic `awk '!seen[$2,$3,$4]++'`

Comment: Indeed, @Sundeep, I think yours is the definitive answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try, the following `awk` code too:

```
awk '!a[$2,$3,$4]++'   Input_file
```

***Explanation:***
Create an array named `a` and its indexes as `$2,$3,$4`.  The *condition* here  is `!a`, (which means any line's `$2,$3,$4` are NOT present in array `a`), and then doing 2 things:

1. Increasing that specific index's value to *1* so that next time that condition will NOT be true for same `$2,$3,$4` indexes in array `a`.
2. Not specifying an action, (so `awk` works in the mode of *condition* and then *action*), so the default action will be to print the current line.  This will go on for all the lines in *Input_file*, and the last line will not be printed as its `$2,$3,$4` are already present in array `a`.

I hope this helps.

Comment: thanks agc for editing it, it looks more neat now :)

Answer (score 1):

This works with POSIX and gnu awk:

```
$ awk '{s=""
        for (i=2;i<=NF; i++) 
               s=s $i "|"} 
       s in seen { next }
       ++seen[s]' file
```

Which can be shortened to:

```
$ awk '{s=""; for (i=2;i<=NF; i++) s=s $i "|"} !seen[s]++' file
```

Also supports a variable number of columns.

If you want a `sort` `uniq` solution that also respects file order (i.e. the first of the set of duplicates is printed, not the later ones) you need to do a decorate, sort, undecorate approach.

You can:

1. use `cat -n` to decorate the file with line numbers;
2. `sort -k3 -k1n` to sort first on all the fields starting at the 3 though the end of the line then numerically on the line number added;
3. add `-u` if your version of `sort` supports that or use `uniq -f3` to only keep the first in the group of dups;
4. finally use `sed -e 's/^[[:space:]]*[0-9]*[[:space:]]*//` to remove the added line numbers:

   `cat -n file | sort -k3 -k1n | uniq -f3 | sed -e 's/^[[:space:]]*[0-9]*[[:space:]]*//'`

Awk is easier and faster in this case.